# Grouping asynchronous messages together

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, rabbitmq, message-queue

I hope the scope of this question isn't to broad, but here goes:

### Context

I'm trying to make a background service in .NET Core that takes a stream of asynchronous and unordered messages from a message queue (in my case RabbitMQ), groups them together and publishes each group of messages as one message to the message queue again. These messages are in the following format:

`<timestamp> - <group-identifier> - <message-contents>`

So for example, given the following stream of messages:

```
2020-12-06T10:10:27.556Z - group1 - content1
2020-12-06T10:10:27.557Z - group1 - content2
2020-12-06T10:10:27.558Z - group2 - content1
2020-12-06T10:10:27.558Z - group1 - content3
2020-12-06T10:10:27.570Z - group2 - content2
```

I want the following messages to be published:

*Published message 1:*

```
{
  "group": "group1",
  "messages": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-12-06T10:10:27.556Z",
      "content": "content1"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-12-06T10:10:27.557Z",
      "content": "content2"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-12-06T10:10:27.558Z",
      "content": "content3"
    }
  ]
}
```

*Published message 2:*

```
{
  "group": "group2",
  "messages": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-12-06T10:10:27.558Z",
      "content": "content1"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-12-06T10:10:27.570Z",
      "content": "content2"
    }
  ]
}
```

### What I came up with

The only solution I could come up with was to use a cache (like Redis) to store the messages, and publish the messages after a certain amount of times
When a message for a new group comes in, the following would happen:

- Push the message to the cache under its group identifier;
- Start a timer of 1 second;
- While the timer is running, when another message for that group comes in, push them to the cache as well with the group identifier;
- When the timer is finished, take all the messages for that group from the cache and publish them;

However, I see a problem with this approach. Waiting 1 second before sending messages is probably enough in my situation, but is far from efficient. In an ideal situation, it takes only 1 or 2 milliseconds for all messages to come through, but it might take longer due to network latency or code that takes too long to execute. But if I shorten this period, I'm afraid I'll start missing messages.

So now I'm trying to find a solution that fixes or (at least) mitigates this problem. But I have had no luck so far. Is this really the best approach, or can I do something differently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the question is how to avoid waiting for one second before emitting the grouped messages? I don't think it's solvable, unless you know beforehand somehow how many messages are going to come in the next moments, that are related and should be grouped together.

Comment: If you have a thousand messages sitting in your queue, do you need to process all of them in order to build up your new payload? What if your subscribers fall over and you have a backlog of 100k messages?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understood the question. You can create a thread-safe singleton dictionary within your application. Whenever you receive a message through the message broker(RabbitMQ in your case) -> try to add it to the dictionary, if it already exists -> modify the value by adding it into the collection with the same key. Add logic to your dictionary(create your type by inheriting ConccurentDictionary<> class(it's thread-safe)) when you add/modify value -> check how many items in the array with that key. Then set up some rule, for instance, once you have 10 items in the array - publish a message to the next queue and remove that key-value pair from the dictionary